# Regex for Windows-1252 Encoded String + (H)H:MM:SS.sss

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I'm using Filebeat/Logstash to parse some log files in which, a couple of the lines are like this:

```
584       +%put Duração Relatório &duracao.;
Duração Relatório 0:00:00.33
```

Using filebeat, I've already set it to use encoding `windows-1252` and the following regex (tested on https://regex101.com):

`include_lines: ["Duração Relatório.*"]`

However this is ignoring the line. Looking at the logs I can see that filebeat is ignoring the line:

```
filebeat_1       | 2017/11/03 10:35:02.337238 log.go:199: DBG  Drop line as it does not match any of the include patterns Duração Relatório 0:00:00.33`
```

Also, my logstash transformations seem to suffer from not recognizing the milliseconds part:

```
grok {
  match => {
    'message' => 'Duração Relatório%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:Duration}'
  }
}
grok {
  match => {
    'source' => '%{GREEDYDATA}/%{GREEDYDATA:docId}'
  }
}
ruby {
  code => "
    h, m, s = event.get('Duration').split(':').map{|str| str.to_i} 
    event.set('Duration', h*3600 + m*60 + s*1000)
  "
}
```

So, my question is, what am I doing wrong and can I have a regex for getting only the second line (String + Duration in HH:MM:SS.sss)?
How do I get the logstash filter to also take into consideration the `sss` part?

Best Regards

### EDIT:

So, the problem of not getting the correct messages was because `include_lines: ["Duração Relatório.*"]` should have been written as `include_lines: ['Duração Relatório.*']`

However, I'm still catching the first line as well, when I don't want to. How can I make sure I only get the string + time?

I've tried using pipes on the regex but to no avail...

Comment: It seems your string is in Unicode, why set `windows-1252` encoding? Try UTF8. As for milliseconds, you are only splitting with `:`. Try `.split(/[.:]/)` instead of `.split(':')`, or just `.split(/\W+/)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your comment regarding the split was correct, thanks. The other problem of messages not being caught was because I should have use ' rather than " on the `include_lines` instruction.

Comment: Ok, so, what is the remaining issue? You want to match lines starting with datetime and then having `Duração Relatório`? Or lines that have `Duração Relatório`, then space(s), then time like `0:00:00.33`?  Something like `Duração Relatório\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+`? `Duração Relatório\s+\d[\d:.]+`?

Comment: Hello @WiktorStribiżew you are trully a regex master :D Both conditions work but I'm sticking with `Duração Relatório\s+\d[\d:.]+`. Thanks!

Comment: Zed, I posted an answer with some explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find lines that have the search phrase followed with space(s) and then time-like substring use

```
Duração Relatório\s+\d[\d:.]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XI57HH/1). A more specific regex would be [`Duração Relatório\s+\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/XI57HH/2).

The `\s+` matches 1+ whitespaces and `\d[\d:.]+` matches a digit and then 1+ digits, colons or/and dots.

To split the time string into components, also account for the decimal separator, which is a dot and use `.split(/[.:]/)` instead of `.split(':')` (or even `.split(/\W+/)` where `\W+` matches any 1 or more chars other than letters, digits and underscores).

Comment: That's it! Once again, thank you! I owe you a beer/coffee :D